# JOptionPane input problems

Tags: joptionpane

Ok, so I understand that if you want to test what the user clicks in a `JOptionPane`, you would do something like this:

```
final int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "That file name does not exist.", "File Name", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

                if(option == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
                {
                    g++;
                }
```

However, what if I wanted to set a String = to a JOptionPane like this?

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("File Name") + ".txt";
```

How am I supposed to compare  what the user clicked then?

Comment: When you're using `showInputDialog()` you want to get user input from a textfield, not depend on what the user clicked

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly will a textfield do?

Comment: User types in some text. You could use a JOptionPane with a combobox to select options. That's another way

Comment: But I don't want the text field on the screen any longer than it takes for them to input the data.

Comment: I don't get what String value you expect to get

Comment: Ok so basically when the user clicks the "load" button, i want a JOptionPane to pop up where they can input the file name. However I want to be able to see if they clicked the cancel button or not.

Comment: Just use `if (s != null){}`. `s` being the return form the `showInputDialog`.

Comment: OK will give `s` a value and `Cancel` wont

Answer (score 0):

When you're using showInputDialog() you want to get user input from a textfield, not depend on what the user clicked.

You can use either a JOptionPane with an input field

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a message:);
```

Or you can use a combobox style JOptionPane

```
Object[] possibilities = {"ham", "spam", "yam"};
String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                "Complete the sentence:\n"
                + "\"Green eggs and...\"",
                "Customized Dialog",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                possibilities,
                "ham");
```

**Edit:**

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a message:); 
if (s != null){     // OK is pressed with a value in the field
    // do something with s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use as you mentioned

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("File Name");
```

Default input dialog has OK button and cancel buttons. Therefore if you press cancel button
your string value will be null
Otherwise it is the value you entered on textfield

so you can have a `if(fileName == null)` 
to check whether user clicked cancel or OK button

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter file name");
if (fileName == null) {
      System.out.println("User pressed cancel");
      //your logic
}else{
      System.out.println(fileName);
      //your logic
}
```